# Optimal trajectory under acceleration constraint

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Let $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $x(0) = x_0$, $\dot{x}(0) = v_0$ Find the optimal trajectory for $x(t)$, such that $$L = \int_{t=0}^T|x(t) - x_f|^2dt$$
is minimized, subject to the constraint $|\ddot{x}(t)| \leq a_0, \forall t$. $x_0, x_f, v_0$ and $a_0$ are known constants.

Any insights on general methods to attacking such problems are welcome. I would appreciate any advice.

**Edit**: I would like to emphasize that essential part of this question is proving that the trajectory is optimal. The problem above is a much simplified version of the actual problem I am solving. Therefore, I ask for the principle of constructing necessary and sufficient equations for finding the optimal trajectory.

Comment: You need an initial velocity as well as an initial position to solve this.

Comment: I agree, sorry, edited

Comment: This is a simple problem in optimal control.

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi So I have heard. Can you provide a solution or a link to literature addressing it

Comment: @AleksejsFomins you can check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_%28control_theory%29?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi Thanks a lot :) I'll have a read

Comment: The problem looks convex w.r.t. x(t), i.e expanding the square inside the integral and using the fact that integrals are linear operators, you'll get something that is quadratic on x(t) and something linear w.r.t. x(t). If you were to try to parametrize your trajectory using some basis functions (polynomials?), you'll end up with a convex QP (the acceleration constraint would also be convex), and then you can use general convex optim. theory to prove optimality? Maybe also looking at infinite-dimensional QPs, and use infinite order polynomials, to not restrict yourself w/ the basis choice?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any general method here so I'll stick with a guess based on simple physical intuition. My guess is that the optimal solution will be to switch between accelerating maximum in one direction, then the other direction (to kill the velocity and prevent too big overshoot) and then stay put (when we have reached the point $x_f$ with zero velocity). For these cases we can easily compute the value of $L$ which could serve as a check against other possible solutions.

By shifting the coordinate system and rescaling time and space coordinates we can for simplicity assume that $x_0 = 0$, $x_f = 1$ and $T = 1$. I will also assume that the initial velocity $x'(0) = 0$. For the case where we are free to choose $x'(0)$, see the end of this answer. Let's split into three cases depending on how large the maximum acceleration is.

If $a_0<2$ then the solution is to accelerate at max all the way so $x(t) = \frac{a_0t^2}{2}$. For this case it's clear that this is the optimal solution and we have $L = 1 - \frac{a_0}{3} + \frac{a_0^2}{20}$.

If $2<a_0<4$ then we accelerate at max till $t = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{(a_0-2)}{2a_0}}$ and then flip the sign of the acceleration and decelerate at max till we reach $x_f = 1$ at $t=1$. For this case $L = \frac{22 a_0^3-120 a_0^2+280 a_0 - 15\sqrt{2(a_0-2) a_0}(a_0-2)^2}{240a_0}$.

If $a_0 > 4$ then we accelerate at max till $t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_0}}$ then declerate at max till $t = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a_0}}$ (for which we are at $x_f=1$ with zero velocity) and then we stop accelerating and stay put. For this final case we find $L = \frac{23}{30\sqrt{a_0}}$.

A plot of the solution for $a_0 = 16$ is given below:

[image]

In the proposal above I have assumed that the initial condition is $x'(0)=0$, i.e. that we start off with zero velocity. If we are free to choose the initial velocity then let's solve by going backwards from $t=1$ starting at $x = x_f$. We stay here as long as we possibly can and then start accelerating maximally so that we just reach $x=0$ at $t=0$ (with non-zero velocity $x'(0) = \sqrt{\frac{a_0}{2}}$). Thus the solution (for $a_0>2$) will be $x(t) = 1 - (t/t_0-1)^2$ for $t < t_0$ and $x(t) = 1$ for $t>t_0$ where $t_0 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a_0}}$. For this case we have $L = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{5\sqrt{a_0}}$.

Comment: There is no requirement that the final velocity is zero.

Comment: @Paul True, but you don't want to have any velocity when you are at $x = x_f$.

Comment: @Paul I think you probably meant to say initial velocity above. I added this case also for completeness.

Comment: I mentioned the final velocity since you mention braking, but as I indicated above the lack of an initial velocity is also an issue.

Comment: @Paul Then I don't understand your point. Why should the optimal solution (in the last case, in the first two I don't have zero final velocity) have non-zero final velocity? Being at $x=x_f$ is the best place to be when you want to minimize $L$.

Comment: @Winther, Thank you for your solution. What you do makes sense, but this is not what I am looking for. It is essential for me to be able to prove that the solution is optimal. Further, I require a general, non ad-hoc way to convert the constrained cost function into equations for optimal solution. Naive approach would be to use Euler-Lagrange, but it does not allow for acceleration inequality constraints out of the box.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Unfortunately I don't know of any such methods and I would be very surprised if there is any analytical method at all that exists to tackle such a problem. Seems like a problem you need to use numerics on. A simple numerical experiment (just divided the interval $[0,1]$ into bins and let the acceleration be free parameters and fit it using MCMC) seems to indicate that one can do slightly better than the solution here (but not by much), but I haven't looked at this very carefully.

Comment: @Winther, are you familiar with Control Theory, namely extensions of Euler-Lagrange and Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equations. After googling, I was actually able to find a solution to a very similar problem, but I am not able to understand it. If you are interested, have a look at https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/fuchs/cv14/cv-14-lecture-9.pdf